# destroy method implementation in pie chart chartjs

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js, pie-chart

I have code to create a pie chart using chartJS. Chart data is displayed based on user input date picker. This works perfectly for the first time. The second time I select the new date range, the chart shows as expected. But as I tap on the new chart, it reverts back to old one.

Below is my sample code:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area").getContext("2d");
        var myPie = new Chart(ctx, config);
```

I found from the documentation that it needs to be destroyed before redrawn. But how can I make it here?

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer by this way.
Thanks!

```
       var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area").getContext("2d");
               if(myPie!=null){
    myPie.destroy();
}
    myPie = new Chart(ctx, config);
```

Answer (score 0):

To destroy chart, you need to call "destroy" method on variable, which contains an instance of the chart.
Simple example for your case:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area").getContext("2d");
var myPie = new Chart(ctx, config);

...some additional code...

// Destroy myPie instance
myPie.destroy();
```